# How to do build this mongoDB query (mongomapper)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, group-by, mongomapper, having

I have certain documents with a `name: String` and a `version: Integer`.

What I need is a **list of documents of the highest version per name**.

So I think I need to do the equivalent of `group by` in sql and then a `having` for `max` version per name.

I have no idea where to start to do this with mongoDB. If anyone could make this query for the mongo terminal that would be a great start, but an added bonus would be to give the sytnax for MongoMapper specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/832455/simon) I had a look at Map Reduce with MongoMapper. My take on it is probably not perfect, but it does what I want it to do. Here's the implementation:

```ruby
class ChildTemplate
  ...
  key :name, String
  key :version, Integer, :default => 1

  ...

  private
  def self.map
    <<-JS
    function() {
      emit(this.name, this);
    }
    JS
  end

  private
  def self.reduce
    <<-JS
    function(key, values) {
      var res = values[0];
      for(var i=1; i<values.length; i++)
      {
        if(values[i].version > res.version)
        {
          res = values[i];
        }
      }
      return res;
    }           
end

def self.latest_versions(opts = {})
  results = []
  opts[:out] = "ct_latest_versions"
  ChildTemplate.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, opts).find().each do |map_hash|
    results << map_hash["value"]
  end
  return results
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Mongodb version 2.2+, you can do your query by using the aggregation framework with the group pipeline operator.

The documentation is here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/

MongoMapper doesn't have a helper for the aggregation framework but you can use the Ruby driver directly (driver version 1.7.0+ has an aggregate helper method).  You would have to get an instance of Mongo::Collection and call the aggregate method on it.  For example:

```
Model.collection.aggregate(["$group" =>
    {"_id" => "$name",
     "max_version" => {"$max" => "$version"}}
   ])
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Well your idea is good but it's my bad that this is not exactly what I need - I don't need only the actual highest version number, I need the **whole** document...

Comment: In that case, you could use the $push operator to collect all the values for a particular field into an array like this: 

Model.collection.aggregate(["$group" =>
    {"_id" => "$name",
     "max_version" => {"$max" => "$version"},
 "other_fields" => {"$push" => "$other_field"}}
   ])

Or do a query after the aggregation and find the document that matches that version and name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a group by with Mongo DB, check the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/), it is the exact tool for the job !

[Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) you'll find the equivalent in Aggregation Framework for GROUP BY, HAVING, and more.

Comment: In this case, see if it support the ancestor of Aggregation framework, [Map Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)

Comment: yes, it appears there are options to do map reduce in certain ways, but it's kinda complicated and you need to implement most of it yourself. If this is unfortunately the only solution, I'll stick with a hack I've come up with for now, since I don't have enough time to figure out map reduce.